# trac-admin deploy not working

Tags: bash, trac, tracd

I'm trying to use the trac-admin deploy command.

```
sudo trac-admin /home/****/repository deploy /home/****/trac_temp/
```

after entering my password i get:

```
Error: Command not found
```

Anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "trac-admin" is not found by root shell. Try to use full path: /path/to/.../trac-admin